# Show that $a = b = c = 0$ for $a\sqrt{2} + b = c\sqrt{3}$ is

Tags: algebra-precalculus, irrational-numbers

This is the following question:

Suppose that $a, b, c$ are integers such that

$a\sqrt{2} + b = c\sqrt{3}$

(i) By squaring both sides of the equation, show that $a = b = c = 0$

The answer says that you put the equation into the following form:

if $ab \neq 0$

$\sqrt{2} = \frac{3c^2 − 2a^2 − b^2}{2ab}$

is rational — a contradiction and so a = 0 or b = 0.

Why would $a$ or $b$ be 0? (I get that you cannot express an irrational number as the quotient of two rational numbers).

Comment: BEcause the last step you took was of form $0(\sqrt 2)=0.$ Which is true but then you can't say $\sqrt 2 = {0 \over 0}$.

Comment: because the expression for square root 2 is rational which is impossible. whenever ab not equals 0 you can get such exprssion.this forces ab=0

Comment: I am not sure about this but try seeing this $2*√2ab = 3c^2 - 2a^2 - b^2$ now since a,b,c are all integers they can't give something irrational as above so I guess it's justified that a = b = c = 0

Comment: Since supposing $ab\ne0$ leads to a contradiction, you have to conclude that $ab=0$. Now, a product of two integers is zero if and only if one of the factors is zero.

Answer (score 2):

If $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$, then
$$
2a^{2} + b^{2} + 2ab\sqrt{2} = 3c^{2},
$$
and then
\begin{align}
(*)\ \ \ \  ab\sqrt{2} = \frac{3c^{2}-2a^{2}-b^{2}}{2}  .
\end{align}
The number $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational;
so $ab \neq 0$ leads to a contradiction,
and hence $ab = 0$.
We claim that $a=b=c = 0$; without loss of generality,
let $a = 0$ and let $b \neq 0$.
Then from $(*)$ we have
$|b| = \sqrt{3}|c|$,
which,
by the fact that $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational,
shows that $bc \neq 0$ is absurd;
hence $bc = 0$.
But either $b \neq 0$ or $c \neq 0$ also gives absurdity,
so $b=c=0$.